# Why doesn't ContentScriptFile work in PageMod?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to inject content script on page and use

```
console.log("starting addon");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",//tempopary
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("testPreload.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'start'});
```

testPreload.js:

```
console.log('testPreload');
```

I see "starting addon" in log and if I use `contentScript:"console.log('testPreload')"` instead of `contentScriptFile` I also see "testPreload".

But when I use `contentScriptFile` I see "starting addon" but not "testPreload". What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Error: `Error opening input stream (invalid filename?)`
filePath resource://jid1-ktaxagdysynpew-at-jetpack/extension/data/testPreload.js

Comment: Is the testPreload.js file in the data directory? It looks like you might have it in the `lib` directory instead.  Can you give the layout of your files? `ls -R`

Comment: Oh, yes he is really in lib dirirectory. So i can't use lib dir if i want to reference from self.data.url?

Comment: No, content scripts must be in the data directory if you want to use self.data to get their resource uri.

Comment: Bryan: you should just answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to move your `testPreload.js` file into the `data` directory.  The `self.data` module is actually referencing that directory so the `self.data.url()` function gives you a valid URL to the files in that directory.  FYI those URLs tend to look like `resource://[your-jetpack-id]/data/[file])`

Again, just move your: `lib/testPreload.js` to `data/testPreload.js` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: What do I do if I don't want to move the script to the data directory? If I'd rather keep it in the root of the XPI? Tx.

Comment: Managed to do it using a nasty, nasty hack that I cooked up: https://gist.github.com/urig/828ddc85e3fd0b79327e

Answer (score 2):

Your contentScript Files should reside in data directory to be able to access it through `self.data.url('scriptname')` .
Move your `testPreload.js` to data directory.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts

Comment: you must say "data" (lowercase), not "Data"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
contentScriptFile: self.data.url("testPreload.js"),
```

Use:

```
contentScriptFile: "resource://<your_extension_name>/testPreload.js",
```

`self.Data.url()` is a function that given a file path will return the full URI path to the file assuming it is under your add-on's `data` folder.

If you prefer to put your file at the root of the package, you can instead build the URI path yourself as in the above example. Just replace `<your_extension_name>` with the actual name you've given to your add-on in its `package.json` file.